# Spring boot, prevent running ddl-auto create drop on devtools restart.

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot with devtools for restarts and spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop

Is there a way to prevent drop/create from happening on devtools restart?

Comment: Do you want `create-drop` to happen when you first start the application and then not happen on subsequent DevTools restarts? Or do you want it to never happen when you are using DevTools?

Comment: @andy-wilkinson I want `create-drop` to happen when I first start the application and then not happen on subsequent DevTools restarts.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing (Spring Boot 1.3.2.RELEASE is the latest version), DevTools doesn't support setting restart-specific properties.

The problem you're facing is an interesting variant of [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4699). Please feel free to comment on it with some details of your problem so that we can consider them as part of the fix.